# path problems porting web-app to phonegap

Tags: android, gwt, cordova

I have what I think is a fairly standard set-up of an existing web-app and would like advice on how best to adapt it for creating native versions via PhoneGap, in a way that we can keep developing the web-app and updating the phonegap generated versions from it with minimal rework.

I am a PhoneGap novice. I have searched around and tried various suggestions from StackOverflow etc with no luck, at least for my set-up.

The app is developed in GWT and consists of:

## static resources in a shared folder for all of the app

/static/ with images, fonts, css.
The css define some font-families, referencing font files in /fonts

We refer to these static resources from html files and JavaScript code using absolute
   paths.

## static resources in a number of sub-folders (by GWT modules FYI)

Such as /LoginGadget, which will have GWT generated html, Javascript and sometimes subfolders with css and css-images.

## GWT-RPCs

These are basically servlets where GWT takes care of serialization etc, and are accessed from our client code via XHRs under the covers

## PhoneGap Build

I have started looking at creating a packaged app using PhoneGap and run into some problems where I need advice (Android example).

I have created /assets/www and put an index.html file in there and got it going.
I copied a version of our /static/ folder and our /LoginGadget folder under that "root" to see, and started it using

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

which works.

In all our GWT generated html and Javascript files we have references to static resources using both absolute (e.g. "/static/....") and relative paths (e.g. from a LoginGadget Javascript, it might reference "css/some.css").

The relative paths work, as they reside "under" the folder where the html/js that references them lie.

## Problem 1

However, references to absolute paths fail, despite PhoneGap starting by saying:

```
DroidGap: url=file:///android_asset/www/index.html baseUrl=file:///android_asset/www/
```

I expected a reference to "/static/images/file.png" from say index.html to be appended to the "baseUrl" to give file:///android_asset/www/static/images/file.png and hence work, as that is where the file lies.

I have had to modify index.html to use "static/image/file.png" for it to work.
But I'd have to recompile all our GWT app with a different configuration to modify all references to resources, and references from other files in sub-folders back to "/static/" won't work if modified to be just "static/".

How can I get absolute path references to "map" to /assets/www or similar?
(See below, I've looked at using the "base" tag....)

## Problem 2

The GWT RPCs make the XHR request to the server the html/js was served from.
This works great as the app doesn't have the host server name hard-coded, and is in fact deployed on many different appengine appids/domains for testing etc.

Here the html/js files are "served" from file:/// hence I need to specify the server somehow.

I tried specifying with the "base" tag as documented, but then any reference I have in my html/js to a resource that doesn't specify "file://" seems to be made to the server specified in "base"..... hence I am not loading my local resources anymore and I basically have a web-app served from my server.

## Want

What I'd like to do, is to be able to take the (pretty large) compiled and tested app from my wab-app's war (/static and all my /GWT-Module folders) untouched and copy them into /assets/www on my PhoneGap app and then add some boiler plate or start-up code and run as is.

Sounds like a big request, but I think if I could properly specify two things:

- file path to use as "root" for absolute paths for resource requests that don't specify a http/https protocol (or other protocols.....which I already see are handled in DroidGap.java)
- server (protocol, hostname, port) to use for any XHR requests

Then everything would come out in the wash!

I thought this would be a faily "standard" setup and already covered. Maybe it is and I'm just missing something.

Comments? suggestions?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: watch out with the customs fonts. Not all browser support it well. Eg. WP7 doesn't.

Comment: I do this type of development frequently. Not sure why you would ever use absolute paths. Use relative paths only as the point of phonegap is to build for multiple devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved these problems with two separate actions:

1) I wrote an ant target that as part of our build takes the web-app, and replaces the paths in all internal url references it finds, making them fit what's needed for them to work within the app. It still seems a major bug in phonegap to me. Maybe it's been fixed in newer versions?

2) We subclassed the RPC service class and modified it to have a static member that is the service endpoint. At the start-up of our phonegap app we modify the end-point to point to the desired server and presto.... all our GWT RPCs point to the right place.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know about mgwt? http://www.m-gwt.com

Its a mobile framework for GWT built by one of the GWT Steering Committee members and it has phonegap integration for GWT apps as well.

There is a lot of docs in the projects and a very friendly user group.

Let me address your problems with a little more detail:

**Problem1:**

If you are using absolute path you will get that inconsistent behavior with phonegap, since the browser builds those urls locally and a reference to / means the root entry on the phone.
Using absolute URLs is a bad idea most of the times and I would recommend you to change that in your app (as you already did).

**Problem2:**

To use GWT RPC with phonegap read this blog post that I made to address the issues: http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/04/gwt-rpc-with-phonegap-revisited.html

Comment: I've taken a quick look at mgwt/gwt-phonegap. If I get things working in phonegap we may well move more of our web-app development with GWT to use them. However, their compiled JS output will be similar I think to my existing GWT compiled JS output.....and so I think I'll still have the same issues I describe in my question?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for that. I had already gone down the path of using SetServiceEndPoint.....but skipped the work of creating a new generator for GWT.create(), but similar approached. I have modified my build to remapp the absolute URLs for paths and works for Android, but for iOS the absolute path can't seem to be determined at compile time as it has a device ID in the middle of the path! :-(